# Default plural form for the singular noun ‘result’

Tags: bug, search, blog, plurals

I noticed the string “{count} results” that is used for search results was updated recently. On [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/?s=%D0%A9), and on the [site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D0%A9) itself I see “1 result**s**”:

> [image: blog]

> [image: site]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site search is fixed:

[image: screenshot of search results page]

Although the top text changed to *"Results for"* instead of *"result found containing"* (not a bug in my eyes).

As for the blog, when I click on the link I get this:

[image: screenshot of the overflow blog]

So it seems to have changed completely. Nevertheless, the pluralisation bug is gone.